# Error in text3d, unused argument

Tags: r

I keep getting an error in text3d, even when I use other people's tutorials instead of my own data - such as this site: http://planspace.org/2013/02/03/pca-3d-visualization-and-clustering-in-r/. Example code with errors below. plot3d appears to work fine, but any ideas what I am missing with text3d?

Thanks!

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(pc$scores[,1:3])
text3d(pc$scores[,1:3],texts=rownames(iris))
#Error in text3d(pc$scores[, 1:3], texts = rownames(iris)) : 
#  unused argument (texts = rownames(iris))
text3d(pc$loadings[,1:3], texts=rownames(pc$loadings), col="red")
#Error in text3d(pc$loadings[, 1:3], texts = rownames(pc$loadings), col = "red") : 
#  unused argument (texts = rownames(pc$loadings))
coords <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(pc$loadings)) {
  coords <- rbind(coords, rbind(c(0,0,0),pc$loadings[i,1:3]))
}
lines3d(coords, col="red", lwd=4)
```

Comment: I can't replicate your error. If `pc` is just `pc <- princomp(iris[,1:4], cor=TRUE, scores=TRUE)` as per your link, everything works a-ok.

Answer (score 0):

R version update to 3.1.3 was the answer (was running R version 3.0.2). Thanks!